# How do I get categories for a product in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I'm trying to add product_type to my Magento Google Base output based on the product's categories, but I seem to be unable to. I have the following code:

```
// Get categories from  product to include as product_type
$categoryIds = $object->getCategoryIds();
foreach($categoryIds as $categoryId) {
    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
    $this->_setAttribute('product_type', $category->getName(), 'text' );
}
```

The issue is that it returns *all* of the categories, not just the ones the product is in. Anyone have a solution?

Comment: This question is more appropriately asked in Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 65):

Using the source link dropped by Rao above I actually found a better answer:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);

$cats = $product->getCategoryIds();
foreach ($cats as $category_id) {
    $_cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id) ;
    echo $_cat->getName();
}
```

Comment: This is sort of the correct answer, but never got marked as correct.

Comment: I am in search of the same.. but where i have to placed this code.. I which folder.. can u give me the path?? I want the list of categories in json format. how can i get this?

Comment: don'T do this, use the solution by Rao, this saves a lot SQL queries!

Answer (score 49):

This is utterly not tested..

```
//load the product 

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);

//load the categories of this product 

$categoryCollection = $product->getCategoryCollection();
```

You can then loop through `$categoryCollection` like through an array.

[**source**](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/42667/)

Comment: This should be the correct solution - by using the collection, you use a join rather than (at least) 1 query per Category. (see: `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product::getCategoryCollection`)

Comment: `getCategoryCollection()` does not contain category name as part of it's select.

Comment: It can do, though, collections are extensible. Try `getCategoryCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('name')` (note: untested)

Comment: @DougMcLean Tested and works. That comment deserves far more credit

Comment: Hello @Rao, here is my code category id not printing -> paste.ofcode.org/3aRT4NyTGRey9AeQ8xnrQtw  thanks for the help?

Answer (score 7):

Want to point out that the solution by @Rao is the best if you have a product object to get category ID's from as it makes only one SQL call.

If you just have category id's, you can do the following:

```
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('name') //you can add more attributes using this
    ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in'=>array(1,2,3)));

foreach($categories as $_cat){
    $holder[]= $_cat->getName();
}
```

Where array(1,2,3) are your categories. Note that the array has integers, not string values, I found that SQL can be picky about that.

Also wanted to point out that solutions pulling one category at a time are very inefficient as it makes an SQL call for every iteration of the loop e.g.:

```
foreach(..){
    Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**Get all Categories of the Product**

```
<?php
    $_Product = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load( PRODUCT_ID );
    $categoryIds = $_Product->getCategoryIds();//array of product categories

    foreach($categoryIds as $categoryId) {
      $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
      $this->_setAttribute('product_type', $category->getName(), 'text' );
   } 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Rao's solution tries to load all the attributes which means lots of queries and joins but you only need a `product_id` to load it's categories. So you can do this:

```
  $product = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->setId($productId);
  $categories = $product->getCategoryCollection();
```

This will not load the product and will give you the categories.

Answer (score 0):

This code work in phtml file in Magento 2

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');//get current product
$categories = $product->getCategoryIds(); /*will return category ids array*/
```